# Difference between days between first and last record in table by ref

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a table with the following columns:

Agreement Ref: Unique ref, there can be multiple agreements for a property

Property Ref: All agreements are aligned to a property

Start Date: the start date of the account (agreement ref)

End Date: the end date of the account (agreement ref).

Handover Date: static date in relation to the property (always the same)

For each agreement ref, I want to calculate the number of days between the start date and the end date for the agreement that was previously in the property. If there was nobody in the property prior to the agreement then the handover date should be used instead of the previous end date.

Please help

Thanks

Si

Comment: Using a MS  SQL database

Comment: what did you try till now?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your select statement:

```
CASE WHEN [End Date] IS NOT NULL THEN DATEDIFF(day, [Start Date], [End Date] ELSE DATEDIFF (Day, [Start Date], [Handover Date]) END AS [New Column Name]
```

For more info on the DATEDIFF() Function: [click here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Stab in the dark. You want to know the number of days represented by +s.

```
--    Prev Agreement                Agreement
-- |Start----------End|+++++++|Start-----------End|

select
    datediff(
        dd,
        coalesce(
            (
                select max([End Date]) from T as t2
                where t2.[Property Ref] = t1.[Property Ref]
                    and t2.[End Date] < t1.[Start Date]
            ),
            t1.[Handover Date]
        ),
        t1.[Start Date]
    )
from T as t1
```